How to generate a random binary invertible matrix?
I need to generate a random n-by-n matrix A with the following properties:

Every element in A is either 0 or 1;
A is invertible;
In the inverse of A, the sum of values in each row is at least 0.

I can generate random binary matrices using numpy:
A = np.random.randint(0,2, (n,n))

In most cases, the generated matrix A is already invertible. However, the third condition is usually not satisfied - in the inverse of A, there is almost always one or more rows with a negative value.
I do not need perfect randomness - I only need a way to generate sufficiently many different matrices that satisfy the conditions 1-3. How can I do this?

Well you could get orthogonal matrices by simply permuting all the rows with precisely one 1 and (n-1) 0 in. The inverse would be just the transpose. Not very random, but there are plenty of them.

@lastchance Interesting idea. Can it be generalized to slightly more general matrices? E.g. If we randomly choose some n different rows with exactly k ones in each, for some integer k>1, is it still guaranteed to be invertible? And with non-negative values in the inverse?

It’s relying on the properties of orthogonal matrices: all rows (or all columns) being orthonormal. Sadly, that wouldn’t carry over to k ones because the row itself wouldn’t be normalised: it would have norm sqrt(k).

It might be worth brute-force testing all the matrices with n=3 and n=4 to see how many such matrices (with elements only 0 or 1) satisfy your conditions, @Erel Segal-Halevi. There are only 2^9=512 and 2^16=65536 matrices of these sizes, so relatively quickly checked.
